# Path to User photo by ID (URL)

Tags: rest, angularjs

I'm consume data by REST:

```
spApp.controller('blogCtrl', function ($scope, $http) {$http(
{
    method: "GET",  
    url: "https://company.sharepoint.com/lgblogg/_api/web/lists/getByTitle('Inlägg')/items?$select=Title,Author/ID,Author/Title&$expand=Author/ID,Author/Title')",                
    headers: { "Accept": "application/json;odata=verbose" }     
}
).success(function (data, status, headers, config) {
    $scope.Blogs = data.d.results;
    console.log('Gettings blog items');
}).error(function (data, status, headers, config) {}); });
```

I can then display this by:

```
<div class="blueDIV">
                <div class="blog" ng-controller="blogCtrl">
                    <div ng-repeat="blog in Blogs">
                        <div class="Title"><a id="NewsLink" ng-href="https://company.sharepoint.com/lgblogg/default.aspx">{{blog.Title}}</a></div>
                        <br />
                        {{blog.Author.ID}}
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
```

This will display 18 (my user id) and i wonder if there some way that i can make a dynamic img ng-src to the authors imag/photo instead of just showing author name.

Im using REST and angularJS.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

We can't expand the `User` field to return `PictureURL`. You need to invoke another Service Call. The easiest option is to query the `User Information List`

```
"/_api/Web/Lists/getByTitle('User Information List')/items?$filter=Id" eq + blog.Author.ID + "&$select=Picture"
```

This will return `SP.FieldUrlValue` and you can extract the `Url` property.

Answer (score 0):

By changing REST to:

```
('Inlägg')/items?$select=Title,Author/ID,Author/FirstName,Author/LastName,Author/Title,Author/Department,Author/SipAddress&$expand=Author/ID')",
```

And then using:

```
<img ng-src="https://outlook.office365.com/owa/service.svc/s/GetPersonaPhoto?email={{blog.Author.SipAddress}}"/>
```

The picture of the Author of the listitem will be displayed, amazing :D

Comment: sry for answering my own question, been on parentleave for two years. And my 10 years of SharePoint Consulting is a bit rusty :)

Comment: No need to feel sorry. It helps people who are looking for similar solutions. Also You can mark your post as answer.